# Find the matrices $A\in M_{n}(\textbf{Z}/n\textbf{Z})$ such that $A^3=I_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If $n\in\textbf{N}$, what are the matrices $A\in M_{n}(\textbf{Z}/n\textbf{Z})$ such that $A^3=I_{n}$ ?

An exercise I found and have no clue how to do. Even if I assume $n$ is prime and we are talking about matrices whose coefficients belong to a field, I don't really see how to proceed. Help?

edit: both the $n$ in the size of the matrices and the $n$ in $\textbf{Z}/n\textbf{Z}$ are the same by the way

Comment: Are both $n$s the same?

Comment: Yes, both $n$s are the same.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  What kind of characterization are they looking for?  In general there are a large number of such matrices.  For example, if $n=7$ then these are precisely the diagonalizable matrices whose eigenvalues belong to the set $\{1,2,4\}$ (these being the cube roots of unity modulo $7$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $n$ is a prime. Let $J_n$ be the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $n$. $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Then $A$ is semi-simple except if:

Case 1. $n=3$. Since $(x^3-1)=(x-1)^3$, $A=I+N$ where $N=0$ or $N\sim diag(J_2,0)$ or $N\sim J_3$.

Case 2.1. $n\not= 3$ and $x^2+x+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_{n}$, that is $-3$ is not a square. Then $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_{n^2}$ and $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{n}$. Thus $\chi_A(x)$ has the form $(x-1)^{n-2p}(x^2+x+1)^p$, that implies $A=I_n$ or $A\sim diag(I_{n-2p},U_1,\cdots U_p)$ where $U_i=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ (the companion matrix of $x^2+x+1$).

Case 2.2. $n\not= 3$ and $x^2+x+1$ has $2$ roots $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_{n}$ (or $-3$ is a square, as when $n=7$). As Jim wrote above, $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_n$ and its eigenvalues belong to the set $\{1,\alpha,\beta\}$.